Screenshot of the Week #132

Hello and welcome to the 132nd edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Joachim's screenshot from metro-exodus won with 7 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for (a little less than) a week, until January 6, 2025, then have a week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at January 13, 2025, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No theme
Uniquely, the last SotW didn't cover both the Holidays and New Year's Eve. So, while this iteration doesn't have a theme, I'll just go ahead and take this opportunity to wish everyone a happy and peaceful New Year!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Congratulations on your win, thanks for posting the SOTW, and happy new year!

You waited an extra day in the hope you wouldn't have to congratulate yourself, didn't you? I keep forgotting that, happy new year!

@pinckerman Thank you! Well, to be honest, it wasn't on my mind yesterday, but today I had the time anyway. And I was going to comment on my selfcongratulatory streak, but figured it doesn't really matter :)

Thanks, @Robotnik!

It does matter to me, lol
